# How do I change social sharing icon in marketing cloud used in mailer?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, content-builder

There is a standard block of social share in marketing cloud. I want to change a particular icon (for example instagram icon, existing one is old one). Please let me know how do I change this ?

[image: social media share - screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You an update the png image in the img src and it will display the icon you want.

```
<a href="%%=GetSocialPublishUrlByName('Facebook', 'US', 'social-content')=%%" alias="facebook share"><img src="**https://image.s4.exct.net/lib/fe911573736c007d7d/m/2/e76b988d-8feb-4d15-b8d9-1ccf4bee17cd.png**" alt="Share" width="24" height="24" style="display: block;; width: 24px !important; height: 24px !important"></a>
```

Comment: Can you please detail *HOW* to do this? In a template, when I attempt to edit the HTML for the Social Follow block, it's locked; the system will not allow you to edit this part of the HTML.